# SQL Server : updating foreign key referential integrity

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following tables in a SQL Server database: A, B & C

- A has a primary key `ID`
- B has a primary key containing `ID` and `A_ID`.  `A_ID` is also a foreign key to `A.ID`.
- C has a primary key `ID` and a foreign key containing `A_ID` and `B_ID`

I want to update B and C's A_ID to a different record, e.g.

```
UPDATE B SET A_ID = 2 WHERE ID = 1
UPDATE C SET A_ID = 2 WHERE B_ID = 1
```

Unfortunately due to referential integrity, I won't be able to update B.A_ID.  If I could, C would have an invalid foreign key.

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89736/4)

I suppose one way to do this would be to delete the foreign key constraint in C and recreate it after the query has run. Is there a way to do this without altering the table structure?

Comment: Your data model implies multiple inheritance from `A`. Can you refactor your table design so `C` doesn't reference `A` considering if already references `B`?

Comment: No, I can't make changes to the table design.

Comment: Can you clarify the FK on C?   How can it "contain" both A_ID and B_ID, when there is no table with both of those as a primary key?

Comment: Good point.  Oops... my mistake.  B has primary key ID and A_ID  I'll update my question.

Comment: I've just had a similar issue to this. Could you combine an insert and select to create, in effect, duplicate data so that you don't get integrity issues, update the child table, then delete the original data that you don't need?

Comment: @RichBenner yes, I could.  I was hoping to avoid that route... but maybe it's the only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to be able to change the PK of a table that is referenced by a FK, you can, as you mentioned delete and re-create the FK.

Or you can re-create the FK with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

This means that if the PK referenced by the FK changes, then the FK will also automatically change.

**EDIT:**  If you mean can you do this without any dropping or altering of the FK at all, then as Rich Brenner suggested in a comment, you can do the "update" in two (four, really) stages, first creating the data you want, and then deleting the data you no longer want:

1. Add new desired data to B
2. Add new data to C, referencing new data in B
3. Delete undesired data from C
4. Delete undesired data from B

Comment: Thanks Tab, although I did say "Is there a way to do this without altering the table structure?"  By which I meant that I didn't want to alter foreign keys.  I'm not sure if there's a better way that I can say that.

Comment: I'd suggest: 1.add new data to B, 2.update data in c, 3. delete old data from B. Only 3 steps to it then

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, why not just use a transaction?

Since `A_Id` in both tables points to the `Id` column in `A` table, I see no problem to update each table's records in 2 different update statements wrapped in a single transaction.
This way, if one of the updates fails, the transaction is rolled back:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE b 
SET a_id = 3 
WHERE id = 3;

UPDATE c
SET a_id = 3
WHERE b_Id = 3;

COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

The foreign key constraints should not pose a problem.
<kbd>[see fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b2b96/3)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Zohar.  SQLFiddle is very useful... I haven't seen that before.  Unfortunately the schema you've provided is not exactly what I intended.  I'll update my question to clarify things.  Also, if I understand correctly, the try catch section of your SQL rolls the transaction back, rather than showing the exception that occurs:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89736/3

Comment: Now I see what you mean. Obviously my suggestion will not work in this situation. Go with Tab's answer. anyway, for future questions, please provide the relevant table (s) ddl statements to avoid misunderstandings like this.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that in future.  Thank you!